# get visidor ip and if visidor is from Estonia then redirects him to that domain

Tags: javascript

So. I work on my website but i want to do something like this. If visidor comes from Estonia, then he will give him a estonian language(Redirects to et.domain.ee domain) and if user is outside from Estonia then redirect him to en.domain.ee domain. I haven't started with script because i don't have any clue where to start. i know that i can use http://ip-api.com/json to get information but from there i don't have any clue... can anyone teach how to do this?

Comment: What server do you use ? And in what language you develop? Give as much details as you can.

Comment: Im using veebimajutus.ee(It's best host you can get in Estonia) host. Standart host. I am developing in Estonian but would like to be English too.

Comment: While I understand you're reaching out for help, this question is too broad for stackoverflow. We're not teachers here, and this is not a forum. This question is opinionated unlikely to help others who come here. Try asking for help/tutoring on reddit or a conversational forum.

Comment: @Dexx This seems to be the XY problem; you're trying to detect the user's language and have read that you can do it with IP addresses, and are now asking how to check the user's country of origin using JavaScript which is quite hard, but actually you just want to know which language to give the user. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: @ wizzwizz4 Yep. I want to know which language they need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of detecting the user's IP address, you can detect their language. It's much more effective.

```js
var language = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
var langCode = language.substring(0, 2)
alert("The user's language is " + language);
if (langCode == "en") {
  alert("The user is English! Redirecting to English site...");
} else if (langCode == "et") {
  alert("The user is Estonian! Redirecting to Estonian site...");
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong in here. If i put my language in english he gives me estonian alert and if im in estonian language he gives only "The user's language is " alert

Comment: @Dexx Try now. Also, where are you putting in your language? And what language is it giving you back?